# Limitation of recursive descent parser?

Tags: regex, recursive-descent

Say I have a simple context free grammar:

```
Z = XY
X = ("ab")+
Y = "abc"
```

My simplified recursive descent parser for this grammar looks like:

```
// takes an input string and returns the length of match, -1 for failure
int Z(str) {
  int len1 = X(str);
  if (len1 >= 0) {
    int len2 = Y(str.substr(length));
    if (len2 >= 0) {
      return len1 + len2; // matches
    }
  }
  return -1; // doesn't match
}
int X(str) {
  // matches 1 or multiple "ab"
  int len = 0;
  while (str.startsWith("ab")) {
    len += 2;
    str = str.substr(2);
  }
  return len > 0 ? len : -1;
}
int Y(str) {
  // matches "abc" exactly
  return str.startsWith("abc") ? 3 : -1;
}
```

The problem is that how can I match "abababc" with this algorithm? It looks like a limitation of recursive descent parser to me, just wanted to confirm, please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

PS: some people mentioned it doesn't need a recursive descent parser, it's a regular expression. I'm interested in understanding the power and limitation of recursive descent parser in this question, not interested in solving it with regular expression. To be more specific, what kind of grammar can be parsed with a recursive descent parser? and what can't.

Comment: Is this `X = (ab)+` really will be used in the input? Means, that `+` plus sign is a real plus,or just an option of at least one or more instances? Please clarify. As the example of input which you gave doesn't contain +...

Comment: Match Y first then match X.

Comment: It looks like a limitation of your unshown code to me, specifically in the methods `X()` and `Y().` Post your attempts.

Comment: It's also really strange to be using a parser for a regular-expression problem. There is no recursion here, so no need for parsing technology. This is not only a context-free grammar, it is a regular expression.

Comment: This context free grammar defines a regular language `(ab)+abc`, this in your case can be matched in linear time. Check for ending `ababc` then check while first two chars are `ab`.

Comment: In this case, if Y doesn't match you'd have to backtrack X until the remainder matches Y or X can no longer be satisfied.

Comment: No. You dont' need any of this check-Y-first stuff or backtracking. You just need one character of lookahead after matching 'ab' in `X()`: if it's 'a', iterate, otherwise push it back and return. But again this is all lexical-analysis technique, nothing to do with recursive descent whatsoever.

Comment: If you want to understand recursive-descent, set yourself a problem that requires it. This isn't one. You gave the game away yourself by using the term 'greedy'. That's a regular-expression concept, not a recursive-descent concept. In any case until you post your attempts at `X()` and `Y()` your question is unanswerable.

Comment: EJP, I'm interested in understanding the power and limitation of recursive descent parser, not interested in solving this problem with other parsers.

Comment: Thanks, seems the + operator is not a valid operator in recursive descent parser, that may explain.

Comment: It's a valid grammar symbol. But, for the third time, until you show us how you're implementing it, this question is utterly futile. And nothing in this problem is going to go anywhere near showing 'the power and limitation of recursive descent parsers'.

Comment: I added the implementation of X().

Comment: EJP, do you have any idea about my question?

Answer (score 1):

A recursive-descent version of your code would be:

```
int Z(string s)
{
    int m = X(s);
    if (m < 0)
        return m;

    string sub = s.Substring(m);
    int m2 = Y(sub);
    if (m2 < 0)
    {
        m2 = Z(sub);    // recursive call
        if (m2 < 0)
            return m2;
    }

    return m + m2;
}

int X(string s)
{
    return s.StartsWith("ab") ? 2 : -1;
}

int Y(string s)
{
    return s.Equals("abc") ? 3 : -1;
}
```

Note that, as @EJP says, this could be done without recursive descent. Recursive descent parses [context-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) languages. Most programming languages are context-free; notable exceptions include Lisp and C++. Parsing these languages require a [recursively-enumerable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language) parser because they allow the meaning of tokens (such as a Lisp macros or C++ template) to change during the parse.